# Modelform not printing fields of one to many relationships

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms

**Summary:**
I have 1 to many hierarchical relationships between models

Country (1) --> City (Many)

City (1) --> Status (Many)

I have a form that is suppose to print the fields belonging to all these models, but when I print I only see the “city” field and that too appears as a drop-down list instead of appearing as a textbox. I tried searching for this problem, but no solutions appeared.

**Code excerpt:**

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms 

class UserReportedCountry(db.Model):
  #country selected by the user
  country_name = db.StringProperty( required=True,
                          choices=['Afghanistan','Aring land Islands']
                         )

class UserReportedCity(db.Model):
  country = db.ReferenceProperty(UserReportedCountry, collection_name='cities')
  city_name = db.StringProperty(required=True)   

class UserReportedStatus(db.Model):
  city = db.ReferenceProperty(UserReportedCity, collection_name='statuses')
  status = db.BooleanProperty(required=True)
  date_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class UserReportedDataForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):    
  class Meta:  
    model = UserReportedStatus
    exclude = ('status’ )
```

Thanks,

**[EDIT#1]**

I accidentally came across this post ([how to make dynamically generated forms with one to many relationships in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122962/how-to-make-dynamically-generated-forms-with-one-to-many-relationships-in-django)) and followed the method that the submitter had used regarding printing forms on the page

A] Forms in the model class now

```
class UserCountryForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:  
    model = UserReportedCountry

class UserCityForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:  
    model = UserReportedCity
    exclude = ('country', )

class UserStatusForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:  
    model = UserReportedStatus
    #hiding the site_is_up property
    exclude = ('site_is_up', 'city' )
```

B] Method that prints these forms:

```
def print_user_reporting_form(self):
    self.response_variable.out.write('<div id="userDataForm">'
                                        '<form method="POST" '
                                              'action="/UserReporting">' 
                                           '<table>' )

    #method call to print the pre-populated user form with users country and city value
    self.response_variable.out.write (UserCountryForm())
    self.response_variable.out.write (UserCityForm())
    self.response_variable.out.write(UserStatusForm())

    self.response_variable.out.write (      '</table>'
                                            '<input type="submit" name="report_up" value= "Report Up">'
                                            '<input type="submit" name="report_down" value= "Report Down">'
                                        '</form>'
                                      '</div>')
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your form is outputting correctly.

You have a one to many relations between cities and statuses.

```
                               country
          __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ | __ __ __ __ __ __ __ 
         /               |               |              \ 
      city             city            city            city   
    __ _|_ __        __ _|_ __       __ _|_ __       __ _|_ __  
   |  |   |  |      |  |   |  |     |  |   |  |     |  |   |  |
   s  s   s  s      s  s   s  s     s  s   s  s     s  s   s  s
```

You have a form that is creating the link between a single status and a city, you can do this repeatedly to create a one city to many statuses relationship.

The drop down is asking which city you wish to associate to your status.

you explicity excluded the status field and take note of [`this`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield)

> Note
>
> As currently implemented, setting
>   auto_now or auto_now_add to True will
>   cause the field to have editable=False
>   and blank=True set.

Comment: Thanks @kriegar for your quick response. The "status" in “UserReportedDataForm” is intentionally excluded as I don’t want that field to be exposed to the user, there is a logic in html form with 2 buttons and depending on the button selected, this flag will be set to true or false. I don’t want “date_time” to be exposed to the user either.

I want the “country_name” and “city_name” to be printed in the form. As you can see from my model declaration, “country_name” should come as a drop down list and “city_name” should be a text-box. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean Text input for the city_name field? or a Text area? I think i see what you are asking for. You want a dynamically populated city_name field based on a user selected country select. That's not possible without ajax.

Comment: i came accross the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122962/how-to-make-dynamically-generated-forms-with-one-to-many-relationships-in-django) and followed the method the user had used to print forms for one to many models. Can you please check [EDIT#1] in my main submission to see if i am doing it correctly?